# How to redirect piped awk script

Tags: bash, redirect, awk

I have problem redirecting `stdout` from an `awk` script.

This script works well:

```
ping dns.google | awk '{print(substr($7,5));}'
```

And the output is printed line at a time.

Now, I want to redirect the output into a file by redirection:

```
ping dns.google | awk '{print(substr($7,5));}' >> latency.log
```

This is not working and `latency.log` is empty.

I tried to be smart, and redirect the output inside the `awk` script like this:

```
ping dns.google | awk '{print(substr($7,5) >> "latency.log");}'
```

Again  `latency.log` is empty.

My `awk` version is:

```
$ awk -V
GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2016 Free Software Foundation.
```

My Linux version:

```
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.3
DISTRIB_CODENAME=tricia
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia"
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="19.3 (Tricia)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 19.3"
VERSION_ID="19.3"
HOME_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME=tricia
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

**How to redirect the `awk` output into a file?**

Comment: permission and storage are not the matter here.

Comment: Please post in your question the output of 1) `ping dns.google | cat -v`, 2) `ping dns.google | awk '{print(substr($7,5));}' | cat -v` and 3) `ping dns.google | awk '{print(substr($7,5));}' > latency.out; cat -v latency.out` so we can see what input is being passed to awk, make sure latency.awk is empty and doesn't just have it's content hidden by control chars and see what awk is making of your input in the case that "works" as well as the one that fails.

Comment: Also try `ping dns.google > foo; awk '{print(substr($7,5));}' foo > bar.out` and see if bar.out is any different than latency.out when you run `ping dns.google | awk '{print(substr($7,5));}' > latency.out`. Just trying to eliminate buffering as a potential cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process pipeline with redirection is non-interactive (i.e. not associated with a terminal) and thus `awk`s STDOUT is buffered and not delivered to your file until the pipe's buffer accumulates enough to be flushed.

One way to circumvent this is to use `unbuffer`. To use it in a pipeline, add the `-p` flag:

```
ping dns.google | unbuffer -p awk '{print(substr($7,5));}' >> latency.log
```

Generally, you will find the `unbuffer` command in the `expect` package.

Another alternative is to use `stdbuf`:

```
ping dns.google | stdbuf -oL awk '{print(substr($7,5));}' >> latency.log
```

Comment: Why does shell redirection affect pipe buffering?

Comment: I would expect the awk's output to be buffered based on the behavior, not pipe.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The blame is the buffering policy. If I allow the script to run long enough the log fills in chunks of 4K. I am no allowed to install additional or update packages. So I am using crude network analysis.